# how to generate numerous points that are random, independent, and uniform on the unit sphere?

Tags: c++

I'm working on displaying a sphere made with uniform, independent, random points with C++ and I do not know how to distribute the points in 3-D. Is there a way I can do this in C++?

Comment: This is more of a general algorithmic question, not specific to c++. Also, random, independent and uniform are not necessarily compatible, depending on your definition of each. Can you clarify your problem statement, and also what you're actually having issues with?

Comment: I think you can do it by selecting 2 random angles 0-360 degrees but I can't prove it - I could be wrong.

Comment: Are you asking how to generate random numbers, or how to select the random numbers from within a range, or how to distribute those points in 3D, or something else? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @MarkRansom You'd want (360°x180°), otherwise you hit every point twice. However, you must choose proper distributions depending on the parametrization, in the standard parametrization, uniform distribution won't work.